# How to select values from mulitple Get statements

Tags: powershell

I want to select values from multiple get statements, joined via pipe E.g. I want a report, that shows me Identity and MailEnabled fields from Get-PublicFolder and FolderPath and ItemCount from Get-PublicFolderStatistics.

Following is the code I tried:

```
Get-PublicFolder -Recurse -resultsize unlimited | select Identity,MailEnabled  | Get-PublicFolderStatistics | Select FolderPath, TotalItemSize
```

I know, I can get the results by using 2 different statements like

```
Get-PublicFolder "Public FolderName" | select Identity,MailEnabled
```

and

```
Get-PublicFolderStatistics "Public FolderName" | Select FolderPath, TotalItemSize
```

However, this isn't ideal when I need this report for over 500 Public folders. Can someone please advise, if there is any better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Without testing it, using a foreach and add-member should get you what you are after.

```
Get-PublicFolder -Recurse -resultsize unlimited | select Identity,MailEnabled  |
Foreach-Object {
    $_.Identity | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "FolderPath" -Value "$((Get-PublicFolderStatistics $_.Identity | Select FolderPath).FolderPath)",
    $_.Identity | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "TotalItemSize" -Value "$((Get-PublicFolderStatistics $_.Identity | Select TotalItemSize).TotalItemSize)"
}
```